# MS Teams - Code Snippet reformatting issue

Tags: microsoft-teams, code-snippets

Whenever I create a code snippet in Microsoft Teams (Mac desktop app) using 3 backticks, the spacing is stripped and text gets reformatted. This is different than the 'Code Snippet' menu item - format is preserved using that approach but sometimes it is just easier/quicker to leverage 3 backticks and drop a block of text into a message.

For example, a code snippet such as this:

```sh
$ echo 'one space | two  spaces | three   spaces | four    spaces'
```

Will be reformatted to this:

```sh
$ echo 'one space | two spaces | three spaces | four spaces'
```

This is most notably frustrating with code snippets where whitespace is significant for either syntax or readability (yaml, json, python, ...). A yaml example:

```yaml
a: b
 - one
 - two
c:
 x: y
 z:
   - three
   - four
```

Becomes reformatted to:

```yaml
​a: b
- one
- two
c:
x: y
z:
- three
- four
```

Or in python:

```py
​def test() -> str:
    return 'mystring'
```

Becomes:

```py
​def test() -> str:
return 'mystring'
```

Does anyone know a way to address this?

I am using Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.8073 on a mac

Comment: I do not have this issue when using teams in browser, In general though - Teams is not something that does formatting nicely. But just in this case, with your examples, it is working fine for me. I would recommend that you try this in the browser, and then try it on teams for windows. Just sounds like an error rather than something you can fix by yourself.

Comment: You are correct @Stoff, the issue is *not* occurring in the browser. So this appears to be a Mac-specific app issue? I do not have a Windows machine to test on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that I can recreate on the Teams app for Windows, nor in the Browser. As such, I can only say that this seems to be very version specific or simply Mac specific. Either way, the only way to know for sure is to test this on another Mac, but at that point you're kind of troubleshooting for Teams. Report as an bug, or technically by the Microsoft wording - "Give Feedback". You can do this at the bottom left of the application itself. First press "Help", then press "Give feedback".

Not sure how seriously they take this, but that is where this sort of thing is supposed to be reported.

(I assume that you've tried copypasting the same code into another software, such as an text editor or an IDE where this behaviour does not exist. If not, please do that before you feedback).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and for testing on Windows. I believe the issue is described on that Feedback forum here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/b078ec60-5a3d-ec11-a81a-6045bd77e4f8